# Why does the directory gets changed in this code

Tags: python

```
  import os

  def rename_file():

  #function definition

   file_name = os.listdir(r"C:\pyscripts\prank")
   path = os.getcwd()
   print(path)

   rename_file()  # function calling
```

*How does the directory is printed as 'C:\pyscripts' instead of 
C:\pyscripts\prank
*

Comment: Please note that Super User is for general computing hardware and software. For more information, see the [help/on-topic]. Programming questions should be asked on [so].

Comment: `os.getcwd()` returns current working directory of the process, so I'm assuming you simply ran the script from `C:\pyscripts`.  Why would you expect it to be `C:\pyscripts\prank`?

Comment: It's not clear why you expect the directory to change at all. `os.listdir` does not change the working directory - it just returns a list of files in the directory that you pass to it. If you want to change the working directory, use `os.chdir`. To see what those functions actually do, please read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os-file-dir).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getcwd()` function returns the *current working directory* for the python script, same as `pwd` command (Unix). So if you need the working directory to be `C:\pyscripts\prank`, then you should do:

```
os.chdir("C:\pyscripts\prank")
```

This works similar to the `cd` command.

Comment: thnks for your help.